# Why PrimeNG column table filter keeps calling a non selected matchMode?

Tags: angular, primeng-table

We have a table with some info, and the last column may or may not have any data related to the endDate of a member.

PrimeNG default date filtering seems to always exclude fields without any info from filtering, so I was asked to put an option to return all fields that does not contain any data. So I registered a 'dateIsEmpty' with merely 'return !value'.

In short:

- I registered two filters on APP_INITIALIZER: 'within' and 'dateIsEmpty';
- I did not overwrite any matchModes;
- I'm using custom ngModel, matchMode, dropdown, calendar, 'Clear' and 'Apply';
- For the date options, I bound the dropdown selection to the custom matchMode;
- I'm using the default filterCallback ng-template variable;

So basically I'm doing `filter(myngModel)` or `filter(myngModel, mymatchMode)` on 'Apply' button click.

For the 'within' filter, it works perfectly, but for 'dateIsEmpty', it always calling the 'dateIs' option, and worse, if I remove 'type=date' from template, it filters with matchMode 'startsWith'.

And when I overwrote the 'dateIs', it iterates with all columns with 'dateIs' passing the same arg, not only the selected column. I really don't get it.

Here is the minimal reproduction on [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-dx5gnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fassets%2Fcustom-data.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

What I'm tried:
I tried overwrite 'dateIs' filter to return empty values if no filter was passed, but seemed to conflict to the clear filtering method.

I tried using custom filtering, with and without 'type=date' tag property, but without it seems to changes the matchMode to text, and with it, only 'dateIs' filter is ever called.

What I expected:
I was expecting that calling the filterCallback('' or null, 'dateIsEmpty') would filter current column with `return !value`, showing only the empty values in the selected column;